# Combinatorics Solution Doubt

Tags: combinatorics

There was a combinatorics question given to us:
The RBI prints currency notes of Rs.2,Rs.5,Rs.10,Rs.20,Rs.50,Rs.100,Rs.500.
In how many ways can it display ten currency notes, not necessarily of different denominations.

My technique:
Let no of Rs.2,Rs.5,Rs.10,Rs.20,Rs.50,Rs.100,Rs.500 notes shown be $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$
$a+b+c+d+e+f+g=10$
$No. of solutions={16 \choose 6}= 8008$

But solution gives answer as $7^{10}$
I know what way they are using but i can't find the fault in my process. Pls help.

Comment: The order of the display counts. Each of the $10$ display positions has $7$ choices, so $7\cdot 7\cdot  7 \cdots 7 = 7^{10}$ possible displays.

Comment: Thank you i got my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your technique is absolutely write.Let the notes are $a,b,c,d,e,f,g $ respectively.So $a+b+c+d+e+f+g=10$.But as you had written "not necessarily of different dominations" , the answer is $7•7•7••••7=7^{10}$.

Remember the formulae of choosing $r$ objects from $n$ object is $n^r$ where repetition is allowed.